# How to compile a Datastage Job using Execute Command Stage or Routines in Datastage 11

Tags: datastage, information-server

I am trying to compile the datastage jobs using the `Execute Command` stage in datastage 11 or any Routines if possible. My datastage is on Unix machine.

I tried the following links to go, but I don't know how to do it.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21595194

So, How can I Compile a datastage job in UNIX from command line or any Routines.

Please help me in doing so.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to compile DataStage jobs in Unix OS.

DataStage jobs can only be compiled from the client machine (which is on Windows). You can do this thru DatasTage Designer Client or by using commandline thru "dscc" command.

Link which you have shared for dsjob command is for running/resetting jobs.

Answer (score 1):

DataStage Flow Designer has a REST API which, among other things, allows you to compile a job using an HTTPS call (perhaps using **curl** command).
For details see [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.fd.doc/topics/rest_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to compile a job? In case of an abort you are trying to compile here you can reset it,

You can reset your job through UNIX server using below command:

```
${DSHome}/dsjob -run -mode RESET -wait -jobstatus ${ProjectName} ${JobName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't.

There are right ways to do things; what you're asking to do isn't one of them.  Your job might try to compile itself.

Comment: I understood that we cant, I want to automate the deployment process of datastage jobs. I dont want any manual human effort for compiling the jobs.

Thanks