# How to export a Datastage job in UNIX

Tags: datastage, information-server

How to export a Datastage job in Unix Machine,

I have tried using the following tools.

`istool` used only for the .isx format.

`dsexport` is used for windows client.

Is there any possibility to export a job to `.dsx` in UNIX machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export/import a Datastage Job using Execute Command Stage in Datastage 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435292/how-to-export-import-a-datastage-job-using-execute-command-stage-in-datastage-11)

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher Can you please answer for the question please sir

Answer (score 1):

DSX is a format on the client and isx the format on the server. 
Check out this [technote](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21635244) - there is no export to dsx on the server.

There are lots of options with isx so it would be interesting what youa re intending to do with is and why you think you need a dsx format.

Comment: Yes, But I want the job or project to be exported to .dsx file so, that I can have a analysis of jobs manually. Is there any way to convert .isx to .dsx

Comment: Well this does not require DSX - the isx is a zip archive unzip it and check out the content.

Comment: oh! thanks sir, so, is there any possibility to compile a datastage job either using routines or any other possible cases without actually triggering the compile button

Comment: Yes - check out this technote https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21432202 and please do not forget to mark this as answer

Comment: But, I want it to run in the unix machine, dscc.exe is not found in it

Comment: Well no support on the server for compile yet. If the answer above is ok please flag it as solved